# Why blockchain is called distributed ledger technology instead of replicated database?

Tags: blockchain

I believe in distributed ledger , data shared between multiple hosts and each host store some part of data while in blockchain each host replicate and store exact  updated copy of records. If this is true then why in blokchain , distributed database terminology  excessively used?

Comment: @Ryan Please correct me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data in a database is generally subject to CRUD operations.  Blockchains are not. Modifying records in a blockchain defeats the purpose of a blockchain.  Modifying records in a replicated database is a daily occurrence.

Blockchain is called a distributed ledger because a ledger cannot be altered.  An accountant in a business cannot just alter records in the company ledger, as its illegal.  Blockchain is the same way, except records cannot be altered because of reliance on SHA-256.